# Spring CamelContext Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

In my application I want to fill endpoint url with *someData* from my application.properties  and fill *header.name* and *header.myId* thoroughly before using myEndpoint.

my_bean.xml:

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" >
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="ref:myProps"/>

        <endpoint id="myEndpoint" uri="...myUrl.../${header.name}/{{someData}}/${header.myId}"/>

        <route id="myRoute" trace="true">
            ...
        </route>

</camel:camelContext>
```

It worked very well, I created tests and everything was great unit I added my_bean.xml to web.xml in order to use a class where I use this endpoint in another class. After adding it to web.xml I got error:

> INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext lis 07, 2013
>   3:57:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Invalid bean definition with name 'myEndpoint' defined in
>   null: Could not resolve placeholder 'header.name' in
>   string value:
>   "http4:...myUrl.../${header.name}/{{someData}}/${header.myId}"

My temporary solution: I added *header.name* and *header.myId* to application.properties (where *someData* is) and it works again but I know it shouldn't be done this way.
Any idea how can I fix it without writing these values to the properties?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in the Spring Framework. We here a FAQ at the Apache Camel website which explains this and what you can do: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html

Comment: I did everything as it says on the website you sent, but it's still not working. I still can not force it not to requre `${header.name}`

Comment: You cannot use simple language in http4 endpoints. If you want dynamic URIs then see this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: @ClausIbsen the url not seems to invalid/removed. This is same for a lot of url that is found over internet.